# IndexOutOfBounds exception coming from Apache when attempting to get vertices from PolygonsSet

Tags: java, apache, geometry

I'm attempting to create a complicated polygon using Apache Math3 [PolygonsSet](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/geometry/euclidean/twod/PolygonsSet.html).  Sometimes, the PolygonsSet can get into a bad state where calling its getVertices() method will cause it to throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception.  This will occur, for example, if I construct a invalid polygon with lines that do not connect.

The particular issue that I'm having is that I have two PolygonsSets that seem to be valid (their getVertices() doesn't throw errors and returns the expected set), but when I union them together using the RegionFactory's [union](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/geometry/partitioning/RegionFactory.html#union(org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.partitioning.Region,%20org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.partitioning.Region)) method, I get an invalid polygon whose getVertices() does throw the indexOutOfBounds error.  The code looks generically like this:

```
PolygonsSet poly1 = new PolygonsSet(epsilon, vertexArray1);
// no errors
poly1.getVertices();
PolygonsSet poly2 = new PolygonsSet(epsilon, vertexArray2);
// no errors
poly2.getVertices();
RegionFactory factory = new RegionFactory();
PolygonsSet poly3 = PolygonsSet.class.cast(factory.union(poly1, poly2));
// errors!
poly3.getVertices();
```

Here's the stack trace of the exception produced:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0  
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)  
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)  
at org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.euclidean.twod.PolygonsSet.getVertices(PolygonsSet.java:712)
```

I would appreciate any insight into the nature of this problem and how to solve/bypass it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger. Please help yourself to some complementary debugging techniques. If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @Ivan The PolygonsSet is underpinned by a BSP tree which is too complicated for me to understand by just reading it in the debugger and it doesn't keep track of its vertices until I ask for them.  Thus it's quite difficult for me to understand the internal state of the polygons.  Unfortunately, I can't provide such an example because the unit test I wrote which creates polygons and then unions off of exactly the same vertices used in the main code does not throw errors.  Because that's weird, I was hoping someone could tell me how this situation was possible in the abstract.